# Why @Autowired ApplicationContext is null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Srping boot 2.7.6, my entry Application class is this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan(basePackages = "fwx.apps.ebidding.**.mappers", annotationClass = fwx.sea.impl.mybatis.annotations.SEAMapper.class)
@Import(SEAPostProcessorSelector.class)
public class EbiddingApplication {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext springContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EbiddingApplication.class, args);
    }

    // make it test-friendly, so we can Override system time when doing uniting
    // test.
    // TODO provide a environment specific offset
    @Bean
    public Clock getClock() {
        return Clock.systemUTC();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(springContext.getBean(DataSource.class));
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession() throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(springContext.getBean(SqlSessionFactory.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public MybatisSEAContext getSEAContext() {
        
        return new SpringMybatisSEAContext(springContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public ISEARequestHandler getISEARequestHandler() {
        return new MybatisSEARequestHandler(springContext.getBean(MybatisSEAContext.class));
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint point) {
        Class<?> class2Wire = point.getMember().getDeclaringClass();
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(class2Wire);
    }

    @Bean
    public ISEAClient createPubClient(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();   
        return new HttpRestSEAClient("http://localhost:8081/sea/", client, builder.build());
    }

}
```

for the `getISEARequestHandler` method, `springContext` is always null, `ISEARequestHandler` is autowired by a rest controller, and I have a `SEABeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` :

```
public class SEABeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private ISEAContext seaContext;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        try {
            seaContext = beanFactory.getBean(ISEAContext.class);
            for (String beanDefinitionName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
                AbstractBeanDefinition bean = (AbstractBeanDefinition) beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanDefinitionName);
                if (bean instanceof ScannedGenericBeanDefinition) {
                    ScannedGenericBeanDefinition sb = (ScannedGenericBeanDefinition) bean;
                    for (String ss : sb.getMetadata().getAnnotationTypes()) {
                        if (ss.equals("fwx.sea.api.annotations.SEAListener")) {
                            String locator = (String) sb.getMetadata().getAnnotationAttributes("fwx.sea.api.annotations.SEAListener").get("locator");
                            log.info("注册SEA监听器：[" + sb.getBeanClassName() + "] ==> " + locator);
//                      seaContext.addListener(locator, sb.getBeanClassName());
                        }
                    }
                }

                String mapperInterface = (String) bean.getAttribute("factoryBeanObjectType");
                if (mapperInterface != null) {
                    Class<?> seaMapperClass = Class.forName(mapperInterface);
                    if (seaMapperClass.isAnnotationPresent(SEAMapper.class)) {
                        for (Method m : seaMapperClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                            String methodMapping = seaMapperClass.getName() + "#" + m.getName();
                            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(SEACreate.class)) {
                                String locator = m.getAnnotation(SEACreate.class).locator();
                                Class<?> entityType = m.getAnnotation(SEACreate.class).type();
                                log.info("注册SEA映射：" + locator + "/c ==> " + methodMapping);
                                if (seaContext.getMapper(locator) == null) {
                                    MybatisSEAMapper mapper = new MybatisSEAMapper(methodMapping, null, null, null, entityType);
                                    seaContext.addMapper(locator, mapper);
                                } else {
                                    ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).setCreateMethod(methodMapping);
                                }
                            } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(SEARead.class)) {
                                String locator = m.getAnnotation(SEARead.class).locator();
                                Class<?> entityType = m.getAnnotation(SEARead.class).type();
                                log.info("注册SEA映射：" + locator + "/r ==> " + methodMapping);
                                if (seaContext.getMapper(locator) == null) {
                                    MybatisSEAMapper mapper = new MybatisSEAMapper(null, methodMapping, null, null, entityType);
                                    seaContext.addMapper(locator, mapper);
                                } else {
                                    String rm;
                                    if ((rm = ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).getReadMethod()) == null) {
                                        ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).setReadMethod(methodMapping);
                                    } else {
                                        ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).setReadMethod(methodMapping + "#" + rm);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(SEAReadCount.class)) {
                                String locator = m.getAnnotation(SEAReadCount.class).locator();
                                Class<?> entityType = m.getAnnotation(SEAReadCount.class).type();
                                log.info("注册SEA映射：" + locator + "/r(count) ==> " + methodMapping);
                                if (seaContext.getMapper(locator) == null) {
                                    MybatisSEAMapper mapper = new MybatisSEAMapper(null, m.getName(), null, null, entityType);
                                    seaContext.addMapper(locator, mapper);
                                } else {
                                    String rm;
                                    if ((rm = ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).getReadMethod()) == null) {
                                        ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).setReadMethod(m.getName());
                                    } else {
                                        ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).setReadMethod(rm + "#" + m.getName());
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(SEAUpdate.class)) {
                                String locator = m.getAnnotation(SEAUpdate.class).locator();
                                Class<?> entityType = m.getAnnotation(SEAUpdate.class).type();
                                log.info("注册SEA映射：" + locator + "/u ==> " + methodMapping);
                                if (seaContext.getMapper(locator) == null) {
                                    MybatisSEAMapper mapper = new MybatisSEAMapper(null, null, methodMapping, null, entityType);
                                    seaContext.addMapper(locator, mapper);
                                } else {
                                    ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).setUpdateMethod(methodMapping);
                                }
                            } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(SEADelete.class)) {
                                String locator = m.getAnnotation(SEADelete.class).locator();
                                Class<?> entityType = m.getAnnotation(SEADelete.class).type();
                                log.info("注册SEA映射：" + locator + "/d ==> " + methodMapping);
                                if (seaContext.getMapper(locator) == null) {
                                    MybatisSEAMapper mapper = new MybatisSEAMapper(null, null, null, methodMapping, entityType);
                                    seaContext.addMapper(locator, mapper);
                                } else {
                                    ((MybatisSEAMapper) seaContext.getMapper(locator)).setDeleteMethod(methodMapping);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {

    }
}
```

which was imported by @Import(SEAPostProcessorSelector.class):

```
public class SEAPostProcessorSelector implements DeferredImportSelector {

    @Override
    public String[] selectImports(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata) {
        return new String[] { SEABeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.class.getName() };
    }

}
```

Comment: what annotations do you have on SEABeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor ? How is it instantiated?

Comment: @Stultuske It was imported by @Import(SEAPostProcessorSelector.class)

Comment: Is your SEABeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor an @Configuration class?

Comment: No, it has no any Annotations on it. @Stultuske

Comment: as far as the explanations of Import I've seen (haven't used it myself yet-) it's used to combine @Configuration annotated classes, so that might be your problem